# Critical value for Wald test of standardized residual?

Tags: chi-squared-test, contingency-tables, wald-test

If I have a table with the frequencies of two categorical variables, I can use a $\chi^2$ test to determine whether there is any association between the two variables.

As part of carrying out this test, I can obtain standardized residuals for the counts of each specific combination of the variables. My understanding is that this value is calculated based on the following counts:

$Z = \frac{Observed - Expected}{
\sqrt{Expected}}$

My understanding also is that I can use a Wald (Z) test to determine whether this value (the standardized residual) differs from 0. My question (if my understandings above are on the right track) is: *What is the critical value for this test?*

With $\alpha = .05$, is it the standard > 1.96 and < - 1.96? Or, as suggested by [this article](http://pareonline.net/getvn.asp?v=20&n=8), is it something a bit more complicated (the square root of the overall $\chi^2$ test statistic)?

Comment: Are you not concerned about multiple testing? (equivalently, do you want an overall error rate of about $\alpha$ or a cell-wise error rate of about $\alpha$?)

Comment: I am concerned about multiple testing.

Comment: Then you probably won't want to do the individual tests at the 5% level

Comment: Could I ask if you recommend the approach recommended in the article above (using $\sqrt{\chi^2}$ as the critical value)?

Comment: The part under eq1.3? It really depends what you're trying to achieve. Personally, I'd try to avoid explicitly testing the cells, only doing so if absolutely necessary (I don't recall encountering a situation where that was actually needed in my own work; I interpret the rejection without it). However, I might often look at the Pearson residuals (your $Z$), in order to find what contributed more to the overall rejection. If you want something with more of the properties of a standardized residual (having the same variance, which you'd want for residual plots or other diagnostic displays),..ctd

Comment: the thing they refer to Agresti for would be suitable. I have sometimes partitioned the chi-square into contrasts I cared about by collapsing. The paper seems to do a fair job of explaining what each of the things it discusses does. If you specifically want to ask a question about the Marascuilo thing you should probably post a Q about that

Comment: I have a separate line of inquiry from Glen_b. You should conduct the hypothesis test as prespecified, irrespective of the residual test. Then you may assess residuals as a sensitivity analysis. Then this significance testing is a kind of pragmatic thing. The curious bit is where you get the expression for $Z$. There is a distributional assumption here, and I wonder if you're aware of it. For $Y$ Poisson, $Z$ makes sense (although there are better expressions). for $Y$ Binomial, not so much!